# Twilio Join Google Hangouts Conference Call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I'm using Google Hangouts for Enterprise that comes with GSuite. When a Google Hangouts meet starts, It gives a dial-in number with a pin.

+1 xxxx-xxxx-3235 , Some PIN number (3495093#)

I'm trying to join this meeting through a Twilio voice call using the Twilio Voice API.

```
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC8bc5f1756b2e10ce344333e0ec6f7acacc46/Calls.json' -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'To=+1 xxxx-xxxx-3235' \
--data-urlencode 'From=+1xxxxxxxxxx6' \
--data-urlencode 'Url=https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/' \
--data-urlencode 'SendDigits=wwwww34975093#‬#' \
-u AC8bc5f1756b2e10c824e0ec6f7acacc46:[AuthToken]
 ‪
```

When I execute the call through CURL I get this response message

```
{
    "code": 21206,
    "message": "Invalid sendDigits: wwwww34975093#",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21206",
    "status": 400
}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here. I'm adding half-a-second wait to the PIN using wwwww. Even passing the PIN without wwwww gives me the same error. 
So my question is, is it even possible to join a third party conference call through Twilio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a hidden control character:

{"code": 21206, "message": "Invalid sendDigits: wwwww34975093#**\u202c**#"

Remove that and it will work.

Comment: Thanks. That was a great catch !

Comment: @ArkoD I'm running into the same issue. How did you fix this?

Comment: @Alan How did you know that?

Comment: One way is to find a reliable website site online to view hidden control characters but I imagine some editors may be able to visibly represent non-visible control characters as well.